# How can I use javascript:void(0) with tag helpers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to implement `modal popup` in `MVC` Application. I have a table with List of Actors and Details. When I click on `Details` I want to receive a form pop-up providing me with the details of the Actor

In my `Index View` I have :

```
       <td><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Actor" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@actor.Id" @*href="javascript:void(0);"*@ class="anchorDetail" data-id="@actor.Id"@>Details</a></td>
```

In my `Controller` I have:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string Id)
    {
        var model = await this.actorService.GetActorByNameAsync(Id);

        return PartialView("_DetailsPartial", model);
    }
```

In my partial I have written an `Ajax` script that I am sure it works but the problem is for some reason the partial view does not even use the script.

If in my `Index View` I uncomment href="javascript:void(0) it breaks.

Comment: What's the point of an `<a>` tag if you're not going to have a real `href`?  Why not just use a `<button>` tag?

Comment: Hi Pointy. Thank you for your question. I use <a> so I can point it to the Actor controller and Details action. Otherwise how else can I point it to go there?

Comment: Surely you can do the same thing with a `<button>`.

Comment: I cannot use a button to point to an action. I have tried this :
        <td><button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Actor")'" class="anchorDetail"   data-id="@actor.Id">Details </button></td>
but it breaks.